# Problems writing binary data to a void* buffer in C

Tags: c

So the scenario is this. I have to implement minimal stdio library in C and the unit test that fails writes binary data to a file and then calls the fread function from my library to read that data. And the problem is that when using `memcmp` on the initial buffer and the data read through my API, they differ.
Have to mention that on printable ASCII characters, it works just fine. The problem is with binary data.

```
FUNC_DECL_PREFIX int so_fgetc(SO_FILE *stream) {
ssize_t bytes_read = 0;
unsigned char c = 0;

if (stream == NULL)
    return SO_EOF;

if (stream->fd < 0) {
    stream->flag_error = 1;
    return SO_EOF;
}

if (stream->buffer_size <= 0) {
    bytes_read = read(stream->fd, stream->buffer, (ssize_t) BUFFER_SIZE-1);
    if (bytes_read == 0) {
        stream->flag_eof = 1;
        return SO_EOF;
    } else if (bytes_read < 0) {
        stream->flag_error = 1;
        return SO_EOF;
    }

    stream->buffer_size = bytes_read;
}

c = (unsigned char) stream->buffer[stream->current_index];

char *temp_buffer = NULL;
temp_buffer = calloc(BUFFER_SIZE, sizeof(char));
if (!temp_buffer) {
    stream->flag_error = 1;
    perror("Memory allocation");
    return SO_EOF;
}

if (stream->buffer != NULL) {
    strcpy(temp_buffer, stream->buffer);
    strcpy(stream->buffer, temp_buffer+1);      
}
free(temp_buffer);

if (stream->buffer == NULL) {
    stream->flag_error = 1;
    return SO_EOF;
}
stream->buffer_size -= 1;
stream->cursor_position += 1;
stream->last_operation = 0;

return (int) c;
}
```

That was the function that reads data in a buffer and provides data from the buffer one char at a time

```
FUNC_DECL_PREFIX
size_t so_fread(void *ptr, size_t size, size_t nmemb, SO_FILE *stream) {
    if (size <= 0 || nmemb <= 0 || !stream) return 0;

    ssize_t bytes_read = 0;
    char *p = NULL;
    p = ptr;
    int i = 0, c = 0;

    for(i=0; i<nmemb*size; i++) {
        c = so_fgetc(stream);
        if (so_ferror(stream)) {
            return 0;
        }

        if (c == SO_EOF) return bytes_read;
        bytes_read += 1;
        memcpy((void*) p+i, (char*) &c, 1);
    }

    return bytes_read;
}
```

And that is the fread i implemented.
I suspect there is a problem casting the data and storing it to the buffer but i cannot figure it out.

Comment: don't use `string`s function...

Comment: Doesn't it seem strange that `strcpy` doesn't need any length parameters? It would be better to divide reading into the buffer into one function, and parsing the buffer into another, this way you get a convoluted function which copies the entire buffer over and over again (`O(N*N)` time complexity).

Answer (score 3):

Your `so_fgetc` uses [`strcpy`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/c/string/byte/strcpy), which is specifically for null-terminated character strings.

If you ever have the value `0` in your binary data, `strcpy` will stop early. Use the `str*` functions for null-terminated strings, and the `mem*` functions (here, [`memcpy`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/c/string/byte/memcpy)) for anything else.

NB. there may be other errors - you haven't provided a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) so we can't completely debug it. In general, making the effort to find the smallest code (and least data!) that reproduces the problem, will either show directly where you went wrong, or make it much easier to step through in a debugger, or in the last resort give you a *really* good question to ask here.